# Structure to allow @tailrec when multiple recursive calls are invoked

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

The following logic identifies the combination of integers summing to **n** that produces the maximum product:

```
def bestProd(n: Int) = {
  type AType = (Vector[Int],  Long)
  import annotation._
  // @tailrec  (umm .. nope ..)
  def bestProd0(n: Int, accum : AType): AType  = {
    if (n<=1) accum
    else {
      var cmax = accum
      for (k <- 2 to n) {
        val tmpacc = bestProd0(n-k, (accum._1 :+ k, accum._2 * k))
        if (tmpacc._2 > cmax._2) {
          cmax = tmpacc
        }
      }
      cmax
    }
  }
  bestProd0(n, (Vector(), 1))
}
```

This code does work:

```
scala> bestProd(11)
res22: (Vector[Int], Long) = (Vector(2, 3, 3, 3),54)
```

Now it was not a surprise to me that @tailrec did not work. After all the recursive invocation is **not** in the tail position.  Is is possible to reformulate the **for** loop to instead do a proper single-call to achieve the tail recursion?

Comment: Comment, since it isn't answering your question. Since you need to examine all sequences that add up to n, generate them all first, then pix the one with the max product - and without any mutable variables `def bestProd(m:Int) = {
     def sumTo(n:Int):Seq[Seq[Int]] =  Seq(n) +:((for (i <- 1 until n; ps <- sumTo(n-i)) yield i+:ps));
     sumTo(m).maxBy(_.product)
  }
  `

Comment: Thx Paul for that alternative impl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible if you're trying to stick close to the stated algorithm.  Rethinking the approach you could do something like this.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def bestProd1(n: Int) = {
  @tailrec
  def nums(acc: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
    if (acc.head > 4)
      nums( (acc.head - 3) +: 3 +: acc.tail )
    else
      acc
  }
  val result = nums( Vector(n) )
  (result, result.product)
}
```

It comes up with the same results (as far as I can tell) except for I don't split 4 into `2,2`.

Comment: So the highest product is always (in regex notation) [2|4]?[3]*   ?  That is apparently the case so your solution does work. Please consider to upvote.